# Segmentation fault in c when reading a line

Tags: c, line

I want to read user input(like terminal) until exit is written or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> is pressed.  I read every line(until return/enter is pressed), check if it's just space or a comment(#) and then execute some functions.

I tried three methods, but no success. I get an error every time I insert a string and press enter

```
char line[256];
while(printf("%s>", shell_name) && scanf("%50[^\n]", line) != EOF)
{
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
while(printf("%s>", shell_name) && getline(line, 100, stdin) != EOF)
```

note: expected ‘size_t * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘int’

```
while(printf("%s>", shell_name) && fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
{
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

for more orientation I'm doing this next

```
if(isspace(&line) == 0 && &line[0] != "#")
```

what am i doing wrong? is there a more suitable/easy/better option?

Comment: Funny -- first thing I noticed is that you seem convinced this is okay: `printf("%s", strcat(shell_name, ">"))`, because you use it everywhere. Try `printf("%s>", shell_name)` instead.

Comment: stupid mistake :) got obsessed with strcat

Comment: Did that solve it? :D So either `shell_name` is a static string (and so it may not be modified), or `strcat`ing lots of characters made it overflow?

Comment: no no, it worked before, it prints mysh> and waits for input, but once I type in a command and press enter i get Segmentation Fault

Comment: You want `*line` or `line[0]` instead of `&line`. Please don't ignore compiler warnings, especially those about mismatching types.

Comment: @rmartinjak: you mean in the `getline` try? The integer also needs to be a pointer. The other attempts show no warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segfault probably kicks in because you enter into an infinite loop: `scanf("%50[^\n]", line)` reads your input and *stops at the Return*. The Return is not consumed and stays in the input buffer. So what happens next time around? `scanf` checks the input buffer, and hey! there is a return! So it stops reading. Et cetera.

Adding a space as the first character inside the `scanf` format string resolves that:

```
int main()
{
    char line[256];
    char *shell_name = "mysh";

    while (printf("%s>", shell_name) && scanf(" %50[^\n]", line) != EOF)
    {
        printf ("you entered [%s]\n", line);
    }
    printf ("done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On a further note, this is wrong:

```
if(isspace(&line) == 0 && &line[0] != "#")
```

-- gcc complains

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'isspace' makes integer from pointer without a cast
warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior
```

The first on `isspace(&line)`, where you probably meant `isspace(line[0])`, the second on `&line[0] != "#"`, which can be written much more concisely as `line[0] != '#'`.

---

#### on `getline`

`getline` works different from the other "get from stdin" functions, because it will automatically allocate memory if asked to. Since it needs to return not one, but *three* results (the number of characters, the string entered, and its length) you need to provide *pointers* to the string and size arguments:

```
size_t line_size = 0;
char *ptr_to_line = NULL;

while (printf("%s>", shell_name) && getline(&ptr_to_line, &line_size, stdin) != -1)
      ...
```

When using this way, you should not use the static string size allocation, as the function will fill in appropriate values. (But don't forget it uses `malloc` and `realloc` internally, so make sure to `free` the result. It uses `malloc` the first time, `realloc` after that to resize.)

Comment: `char *ptr_to_line = line;` will get you in trouble here if `getline` wants to reallocate the buffer. Using `0` and `NULL` is the better option!

Comment: Thanks, changed "can" to "should". That should do it :)

Comment: I'd change the whole code block. You can never be sure that there's nobody out there that will just use it without reading the text beneath it.

Comment: @rmartinjak actually, if i press space(once or several times) and then press enter program does not ignore it, but is still waiting for input. Also, how would i ignore enter, tried line[0] != '\n', but it doesn't work